# What is the difference between "cloud-init.log" and "cloud-init-output.log"?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cloud-init

I noticed in my EC2 instances (spun up by CloudFormation) that a `cloud-init.log` and a `cloud-init-output.log` file exists on `/var/log`.

What is the difference between the two? Are they the output of the same script, or different scripts?